# Get driver location for particular printer via command line

Tags: osx, printing, cups

This is on OS X 10.8. I want to be able to arbitrarily pull the configuration for a particular printer, so I can use it in a package-creation script. The script (not mine) uses

```
/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p "$printername" -L "$location" -D "$gui_display_name" -v "$address" \
-P "$driver_ppd"
```

to set up a new printer.

If I supply `$printername` on the system I'm pulling from, I can get `$location` and $address from `lpoptions`. But I can't seem to find a command that will give me `$driver_ppd` (which takes the form `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/HP LaserJet P4010_P4510 Series.gz`).

I know it's available to the system because I can see it in the CUPS web interface under that printer.

Comment: Try parsing the config file, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @FaheemMitha. Unfortunately, the only config file I can find (`/etc/cups/printers.conf`) spits out the same information as `lpoptions`, i.e. no driver location. Nothing else in /etc/cups seems to have it either.

Comment: On my system (Debian wheezy), the PPD files are stored as `/etc/cups/ppd/printername.ppd`. Assuming a similar schemes holds on other systems, you really just need the printer name, which you can get from `/etc/cups/printers.conf`. This appears to be in XML format, so you could probably use some suitable XML parsing tool.

Comment: Hmm. While `/etc/cups/ppd/$printername.ppd` does have all the information I need (it's a copy of the driver file with options tweaked), that file is only present after the printer hass been installed. I was looking for a way to run a script on a system where the printer isn't installed yet, without having to also deliver the ppd file. (The drivers would already be installed as a separate package.) That said, if I can't make that work, this might very well be the best workaround. Thanks!

Comment: "I was looking for a way to run a script on a system where the printer isn't installed yet, without having to also deliver the ppd file." I doubt this is something that can be done automatically. Shall I go ahead and add my previous observation as an answer?

Comment: I don't think I've been clear about what I'm looking for, or maybe it's a difference between OS X and Linux. On OS X, if for example the HP Drivers are already installed, I can just run `lpadmin -p "HP4515" -L "$location" -D "$gui_display_name" -v "$address" -P "$hp4515driver"`, where $hp4515driver is the location of the installed driver, and the printer will work. So it's definitely possible to install without delivering HP4515.ppd from the old machine. If I could just find out which driver file a particular installed printer is using, it would be simple. I'm not ready to give up on that yet.

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Debian wheezy), the PPD files are stored as `/etc/cups/ppd/printername.ppd`. Assuming a similar scheme holds on other systems, you really just need the printer name, which you can get from `/etc/cups/printers.conf`. This file appears to be in XML format, so you could probably use some suitable XML parsing tool.